# Invalid type in JSON write (RTCIceCandidate)

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, dictionary, websocket

I am using websocket to call received, accept and all. I am getting websocket event when call accepted.

websocket accept event output :-

```
{
    action = signal;
    "call_id" = 60a4d5b4850b3875f95dbc6e;
    event = CALL;
    from = 5b30ec0fa4cef4609038470b;
    id = "330A1A48-A6BA-4B29-A4A2-9D9FDB85144D";
    signal =     {
        offer = "RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCIceCandidate):\naudio\n0\ncandidate:1211696075 1 udp 41885439 3.8.66.208 62545 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag DT/j network-id 1 network-cost 10\nturn:3.8.66.208:3478?transport=udp";
    };
    to = 5b4854724f82e91934c1c475;
}
```

I am converting above dictionary object to json string using below code.

```
-(NSString *)convertDictionaryToJsonString:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return jsonString;
}
```

Problem :- It's crash the app and reason is - `'Invalid type in JSON write (RTCIceCandidate)'`

Can anyone know that how to avoid crash and solved this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your dictionary seems fine as such. Can you either tell more about `dict` (there is a `RTCIceCandidate` object?) Is `dict[@"signal"][@"offer]` really a `NSString` or that's custom description?

Comment: (RTCIceCandidate) - it is in "offer" key value but whole thing is as a string. so its could be work.

Comment: @Larme i have edited question with full response of `dict`

Comment: Is that code inside your pod https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/ThirdParty/libwebrtc/Source/webrtc/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/RTCIceCandidate%2BJSON.m ? Else, could you check the type of each property: `NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass([dict[@"signal"][@"offer] class]));`. I guess it's returning `RTCIceCandidate`, because that's the `description` of it: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/ThirdParty/libwebrtc/Source/webrtc/sdk/objc/api/peerconnection/RTCIceCandidate.mm#L37

Comment: okay let me put log and check

Comment: @Larme yes it's printing `Class: RTCIceCandidate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the valid types for JSON:

> A Foundation object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - Numbers are not `NaN` or `infinity`.

Your error is saying that at some point, there is an object which is not of the allowed type, it's of `RTCIceCandidate`.

Seeing `"RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCIceCandidate):\naudio\n0\ncandidate:1211696075 1 udp 41885439 3.8.66.208 62545 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag DT/j network-id 1 network-cost 10\nturn:3.8.66.208:3478?transport=udp"` make you think that's it's indeed a `NSString` BUT, if we see the code of `RTCIceCandidate` (since it's the culprit class), we see an override a [`description`](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/ThirdParty/libwebrtc/Source/webrtc/sdk/objc/api/peerconnection/RTCIceCandidate.mm#L37):

```
- (NSString *)description {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RTCIceCandidate:\n%@\n%d\n%@\n%@",
                                    _sdpMid,
                                    _sdpMLineIndex,
                                    _sdp,
                                    _serverUrl];
}
```

There is a [RTCIceCandidate+JSON extension](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/ThirdParty/libwebrtc/Source/webrtc/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/RTCIceCandidate%2BJSON.m) which provide some interesting way to convert `RTCIceCandidate` into JSONString/JSONData.

You need to replace the culprit object with an object of allowed class.

```
RTCIceCandidate *candidate = dict["signal"]["offer"];
NSString/NSDictionary *candidateValid = //Whatever the method you want with a method from RTCIceCandidate+JSON, custom one ?

dict[@"signal"] = @{@"offer": candidateValid}; //Because I guess that dict[@"signal"] is in a fact a `NSDictionary` and not a `NSMutableDictionary`

//Current code
```